# Please help: my 3 year old won't stay in her bed!

Tags: toddler, sleep

Well this started about 3 months ago and it's been on going no matter where my daughter stays! She's an absolute diamond going to sleep but staying asleep is a different matter.

I'm pregnant with another Lil Girly. My daughter is very excited about that and I have
been involving her in everything!

I have thought about what has changed: well, my new partner has moved in with me, and my daughter's dad has a new flat and a new girlfriend!

My daughter loves spending time with everyone. She doesn't like staying asleep! I've tried night lights, toys, even a new bedroom!! I'm running out of ideas as to what the problem could be.

She can stay awake all day and all night, but 3 months is a long time. Every day I'm getting a headache and I suffer from seizures so I need my sleep :(:( Help!!!

Comment: [This related question and answers may help](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4708/advice-for-carrying-out-the-stay-in-bed-technique-with-our-2-year-old?rq=1).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like she's got a lot of changes going on at once: new baby on the way, Dad has a new girlfriend and a new home, Mom has a new boyfriend who now lives with you guys.  That's a LOT for a 3-year-old to process.

Is there any way you and/or Dad could devote some additional one-on-one time to her?  Since you say she doesn't want to be alone, that reinforces to me that she's feeling insecure about her position in her new family situations and needs some reassurement that she's still loved and treasured and needed.  My three-year-old flipped out for a while when her brother arrived, and that was without the other challenges your daughter is facing.

Good luck!