# My 2-year-old doesn't want to sleep through the night and drinks 5-7 bottles per night

Tags: toddler, sleep, bottle-feeding

My 2-year-old girl has never slept through the night. She used to wake 3 times a night for a bottle and then 5 times a night for a bottle now she is so bad she wakes up 10-15 times a night and won't go back to sleep without drinking her bottle.

I'm getting little to no sleep in the evenings. I don't know why she wakes up so many times.
But what I do know is that she won't stop crying and go back to sleep without a bottle.

I need help on getting her to sleep through all the way through the night.

I read her books, nice warm bath, settling time. she is not hot or cold, thirsty or hungry.
It's just a bad habit and I don't know how to break it. Why does she wake so many times?

Comment: How much does she eat/drink during the day?  If you haven't yet, please measure this precisely, particularly with liquids (use the same cup all day, put an exact amount of water in it each time you fill it, and measure total ounces).

Comment: @Julz what is in the bottle? Milk? Also, how long does it take her to fall back to sleep after you give her the bottle? Does she finish it, or just take a few sips and then doze off?

Comment: She finishes 7 bottles of milk in the evening.

Comment: Ask a doctor to check for diabetes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting a 2-year-old back to sleep in the middle of the night](http://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/4600/getting-a-2-year-old-back-to-sleep-in-the-middle-of-the-night)

Comment: I'm voting to leave this open. While the underlying issue is the same, I believe the causes are different.

Comment: This is not about sleep problems - a two-year-old drinking SEVEN bottles of milk indicates other root causes.

Answer (score 5):

Talk to your doctor about her nighttime habbits. Also I would think that it is probibly time to say bye bye to the bottle. Again, double check with the doctor but they need to get all their nutrition during the day.

We stopped night time bottles with my son around 8 months if I remember correctly. It was hard for all of us. He would wake up and cry for a long time, but after 2 or three nights he started sleeping a lot better.

Answer (score 4):

We had a similar problem.

The solution was for us was to put a leakage-proof water bottle into her bed. She would wake up at night, take a sip, lie down again and continue sleeping. The bottle would just lie beside her ( It was a NUK Easy Learning Cup ). That gave her the comfort she would need at nightly sleep interruptions.

After we got a bigger bed for her with 2 1/2 years we converted the bottle to an open plastic glass with water that stands beside the bed.

As soon as we felt she was self-aware enough to go go the bathroom alone at night we stopped the glass of water beside the bed because it was a bit prone to be knocked over accidentally.

Comment: I still have to have water next to the bed to sleep, and I'm 33. I'm wondering if this is why...just saying...

Answer (score 1):

> I'm getting little to no sleep in the evenings. I don't know why she wakes up so many times. But what I do know is that she won't stop crying and go back to sleep without a bottle.

Toddlers are very much habit creatures. you might have slowly build up this habit by always giving the bottle whenever the baby would cry in the past. So this habit was born.

Breaking habits is hard and might involve a lot of crying, but my suggestion would be to not give the bottle at all anymore at night (at 2years they definitely don't need it anymore). let her cry come and calm her 5-10-15 minutes (just like sleep training). that's how you train your toddler to fall a sleep on his own.

Ofcourse also care for yourself if this is too much of a strain on you, I would do like others suggest and first try a non-leaking cup for a while.